# keypress event does not work in knockout js

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

When i press key, then i can not go to debugger into method CheckConfirmPassword, what was the problem.Thank you

html Code:

```
<div class="zseparatornext" data-bind="with: OrganiserObservable">
<div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="ConfirmPassword">Confirm Password</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input id="ConfirmPassword" name="ConfirmPassword" class="input-large" type="password" data-bind="value: $parent.confirmPassword, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown', event: { keypress: $parent.CheckConfirmPassword }">
                <span data-bind="text: PasswordMatch" />
            </div>
        </div>
 </div>
```

View Model Code:

```
var CheckConfirmPassword = function (data, event) {
        alert("developping....");
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use the `event` binding here.

Your `confirmPassword` observable is already being updated after keydown (in other words: instantly), just base a computed on it.

HTML

```
<input … data-bind="value: $parent.confirmPassword, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'">
<span data-bind="text: passwordsMatch" />
```

Model

```
function Model() {
    this.password = ko.observable();
    this.confirmPassword = ko.observable();
    this.passwordsMatch = ko.computed(function () {
        return this.password() === this.confirmPassword();
    }, this);
}
```

`passwordsMatch` will be `true` in the instant the passwords are equal.

Answer (score 0):

use keyup instead of keypress, now it will be work.